# what's the future of SharePoint onprem, SharePoint adminstrator jobs

Tags: discussion

As stackoverflow survey and other indicators. ,  Many companies already moved to cloud and office 365.

I am worried and disappointed, linkedin shows less jobs for SharePoint admins!!!! I don't know What's the future for me as SharePoint adminstrator, what's the right path should I learn, is it azure, SharePoint online. Please help me.

Comment: Why it's closed? Please, open it again, it's very important question for all SharePoint admins 

Comment: Maybe this better asked in meta

Comment: Totally agree, it's an important question, but based on the SE policies it's primarily opinion-based :( I will migrate it to meta as @JamesRandal suggested

Comment: Check this good ref [SharePoint Roles and Responsibilities (SharePoint Online)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fromthefield/2015/08/03/sharepoint-roles-and-responsibilities-sharepoint-online/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are more features to administer in Office 365.  SharePoint Online is just one of them.

Your understanding of sites, web, metadata, content types, search, taxonomy will still be needed, if not more.  In addition, you need to understand modern sites, hub sites, Office 365 Groups, Teams, Stream integration, Forms, Yammer/Teams/SharePoint's outer loop and inner loop.

Your skills with PowerShell, with PnP-PowerShell or SPO-cmdlets, will need to increase to include Azure and Exchange.  You will run them in Azure Automation or Azure Functions, and build massive automation steps to manage an ever increasing set of triggers and webhooks.  Some of these are building blocks only you as an admin can do, and you need to build these building blocks for your business analysts that are rolling out PowerApps, Flow or developers building custom SPFx webparts.

Your job as a SharePoint administrator is only finished if you consider there's nothing left to do.  There is actually so much more to be done.

Comment: Thank you John, it's awesome answer! Could you please share azure and office 365 career/learning path?

Comment: soothing answer, I forwarded to my friends. :)

Comment: Many features in Office 365 are build upon SharePoint Online in one way or another. A good understanding of SP is vital to manage O365. Understanding OnPrem is a good start.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest challenge of a successful SharePoint implementation are still unchanged after 15 years. User adoption and moving away from shared drives and using email with attachments. Very few of the orgs I heard about and none of the ones I worked with had a vision for SharePoint or a strategy to become a true digital workplace. This field is still in desperate need of attention as any fancy thing you can do through coding will not affect user adoption or a wide cultural change in the way data is processed.

If you see your job as administrator as a solution creator and an evangelist using out of the box tools (no coding involved) there is still a lot to do as content types, taxonomy etc are still unchanged.